# ASP.NET Core 2.1 EF - One to One relationship generates foreign key constraint only on one side of the relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following two models:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

After running `Add-Migration <some-name>` I noticed that the generated migration creataed a FK for the `ShoppingCartId` column in the `AspNetUsers` table (the one represented by the `ApplicationUser` class), but the other way around on the side of the `ShoppingCart` table, there was no FK created for the `UserId` column.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: In the relational model 1-1 relationships are typically implemented with a FK on only one table.  Otherwise you wouldn't be able to insert a row into either table on many RDBMS platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the relationship the wrong way around.

A user doesn't "have" a shopping cart (or at least it doesn't have to, for example when newly registered), a cart "belongs to" a user. You also might want to model this in such a way that a user (maybe not now, but later) is the owner of multiple shopping carts.

So:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Later: public List<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCarts { get; set; }
    public ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }
}
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion leaves me with the following error when generating the migration: `The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'ShoppingCart.ApplicationUser' and 'ApplicationUser.ShoppingCart'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property.`

Comment: Fixed it - I had to rename the `ApplicationUser` property to `User`. After that, your suggestion solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you put `public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }` ApplicationUser as a property to your Entity Model, it creates relationship for you.

But I do not suggest you to do that, do not tightly couple all your application tables with Application Identity. It is also adviced to put your Authentication context on seperate Database Context schema

Comment: I only have one entity in my whole DB model which is tied with Application Identity, and that is `ShoppingCart`, so that's not the case here. Also, I have already placed the property as you can see.